# How to: Mount an Azure Storage File Share to On-premise cluster

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-file-share

I have been using AKS service and Azure file share but I want to test some applications on-premise and I want to mount my file share on an on-premise cluster

I want to create secrets and they should be running

In AKS I have been creating secrets and it is working as expected

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are ways to achieve this.

1. You will need to have the Azure File share created in Azure obviously.
2. Install cifs-utils
3. To securely provide the Azure Files share username and access key to your on-premises server, create a credentials file that is only readable by yourself (root?)
4. Mount the file share to your on-premises "server": `sudo mount -t cifs //<STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME>.file.core.windows.net/<SHARE_NAME> <MOUNT_POINT> -o credentials=/etc/smbcredentials/<SHARE_NAME>.cred,serverino,vers=3.0,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777`  -adjust the permissions after needs.
5. Verify the mount points is available by either `ls <MOUNT_POINT>`  or `df -h`
6. Optionally add the mount point to /etc/fstab so that the share is available after a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers

I found solution for this

1. you need cifs-utils
2. on azure fileshare there is an option called "connect" where you just need to select os and you will get the script ( in my case Linux and I got shell script )
   just run that script it will automatically mount to the VM